# Online Java-Code analyser

Tags: java

Does somebody know if there is a online code analyser for java. I would like to be able to check some small pieces of code.

Ex:  this method has this warning: (Null Dereference)

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar asXMLGregorianCalendar(Date data) {
            DatatypeFactory dateformat = null;
            try {
             dateformat = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
            } catch (MyException e) {
                 ///
            }
           if (data == null) {
           return null;
           } else {
          GregorianCalendar gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar();
          gregorianCal.setTimeInMillis(data.getTime());
          return dateformat.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCal );
    }
}
```

My new version is :

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar asXMLGregorianCalendar(Date data) throws ComponentBlockingException {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        DatatypeFactory dateformat = null;
        try {
            dateformat = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            ////
        } 
        GregorianCalendar gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar();
        gregorianCal.setTimeInMillis(data.getTime());
        return dateformat.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCal );

    }

}
```

I think the second way should be ok.

Comment: I don't know about online tools, but most recent IDEs should cover that type of use case.

Comment: Maybe ide one [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) ?

Comment: [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is not online, but it can be helpful with these kind of things, and has a decent Eclipse plugin. It also integrates with Maven, Idea, and NetBeans.

Comment: Include the last thre lines within the try block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about any available online code anlayzer tool but let me try to help you with your code analysis.

If due to some reason following try block hits an an exception

```
try {
        dateformat = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
    }
```

then your dateformat will remain null. So the following statement

```
return dateformat.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCal );
```

is prone to null pointer exception. And hence i believe you are getting static code anlayzer error.

You have to make sure dateformat is initialized or non-null in all the case before code reaches the line where you are doing the return.

Hope it helps!

Comment: other exception than the one i catch it because if it's MyException everything should be ok because it will never arrive at `return`

Comment: No the point is that if an exception occurs no matter MyException or other exception then dateformat will be null. So in that case there is no point calling  return dateformat.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCal );
So you should either throw an exception or simply return from the method.

Comment: @Juned, you are doing the analysis, not answering the question!

Comment: @Tom I am just trying to help as i believe the end requirement is to know what is the problem.

Comment: @JunedAhsan - I see that and it is good of you, but the question clearly asks about online code analysers.  I'm interested to see if anyone posts a real one.